# Bash string replacement with regex repetition

Tags: regex, string, bash, replace, repeat

I have a file: filename_20130214_suffix.csv
I'd like replace the yyyymmdd part in bash. Here is what I intend to do:

```
file=`ls -t /path/filename_* | head -1`
file2=${file/20130214/20130215}
#this will not work
#file2=${file/[0-9]{8}/20130215/}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that parameter expansion does not use regular expressions, but patterns or globs(compare the difference between the regular expression "filename_.*.csv" and the glob "filename_*.csv"). Globs cannot match a fixed number of a specific string.

However, you can enable extended patterns in `bash`, which should be close enough to what you want.

```
shopt -s extglob    # Turn on extended pattern support
file2=${file/+([0-9])/20130215}
```

You can't match exactly 8 digts, but the `+(...)` lets you match one or more of the pattern inside the parentheses, which should be sufficient for your use case.

Since all you want to do in this case is replace everything between the `_` characters, you could also simply use

```
file2=${file/_*_/_20130215_}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[[ $file =~ ^([^_]+_)[0-9]{8}(_.*) ]] && file2="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}20130215${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```